# Find as many solutions of the IVP $y-(\sin x) y'=0, y_0 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find as many solutions of the IVP $y-(\sin x) y'=0, y_0 = 0$

Integrating gives us

$$\ln |y|=\ln k+|\tan x/2|$$
$$ |y|=k|\tan x/2|$$.

Now seeing that $y=k\tan x/2$ or $y=-k \tan x/2$ do we say that there are two general solutions or no solution as |y| can not have two values for a same value of x.

Comment: Do you mean $$y-\sin(xy')=0$$?

Comment: The solution is given by $$y(x)=\sin \left(\text{CosIntegral}^{(-1)}(c_1+\log
   (x))\right)$$

Comment: What do you mean by IVP ?

Comment: @Rishi initial value problem, i.e. a differential equation with given initial condition

Answer (score 1):

See this graph , $ |y|=|tan {x \over 2}|$. And observe a point (x,y) & ${dy \over dx}$ is slope of curve.
[image]

Comment: so there are infinite solutions?

Comment: For every value of k there is a solution , so there are infinite solutions.But if you consider a particular value then open modulus as tan x/2 < / > or x < / > 0 , for each cases and check slope and see if they satisfy your equation. It will clear you confusion